# MSSQL-OPENROWSET, Passing dates in dynamic query

Tags: sql-server

This shouldn't be so hard, but I just can't seem to find where I am going wrong. The following gives me a syntax error (a very non descriptive one). The reason that I am doing it this way is that I eventually want to replace the dates with the values from variables.

A second(or third) set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=WIN- 
T7HOHROSTNT\SQLEXPRESS;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;database = MyDB'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [MyDB].[dbo].[GetCourseReport]
        @Start = N''22 Jan 2014 4:00pm'',
        @End = N''23 Jan 2014 4:00pm'',
        @QueryTime = N''22 Jan 2014 8:00pm'',
        @CourseSUID = 1'') AS Result'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
```

I get the above code from doing a copy/paste from the below query, which does indeed work;

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=WIN-T7HOHROSTNT\SQLEXPRESS;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;database = MyDB',
'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [MyDB].[dbo].[GetCourseReport]
        @Start = N''22 Jan 2014 4:00pm'',
        @End = N''23 Jan 2014 4:00pm'',
        @QueryTime = N''22 Jan 2014 8:00pm'',
        @CourseSUID = 1') AS Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a a horrible work around, but it at least works in a pinch. I passed the dates a s numbers then do a check on the procedure side to determine which one to use. I saw search results on ISO dates, but could never get it to work. If anyone else gets something to work, I'd love to know about it.

```
DECLARE @startTime  DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-22-2014 4:00pm');
DECLARE @endTime    DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-23-2014 4:00pm');
DECLARE @queryTime  DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-23-2014 2:00am');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000) = N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=WIN-T7HOHROSTNT\SQLEXPRESS;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;database = MyDB'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [MyDB].[dbo].[GetCourseReport]
    @Start = NULL,
    @End = NULL,
    @QueryTime = NULL,
        @CourseSUID = NULL, 
    @StartAsNumber = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,10), @startTime)) + ',
    @EndAsNumber = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,10), @endTime)) + ',
    @QueryAsNumber = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,10), @queryTime)) + '    
    '')'


PRINT @sql

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```